# How to write this Complex Query in JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
SELECT distinct programme_number FROM (
(
SELECT p.*
FROM Programme p, Alloc A, session s, session_res sr, res r
WHERE p.ID = A.programme_id
AND A.ID = s.alloc_id
AND sr.session_id = s.ID
AND sr.ID = r.ID
ORDER BY r.start_date DESC));
```

Basically one programme can have many "res" and needs sorting on "res" start date but should return one or distinct programme.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you're merely faking a standard RDBMS join using the where clause in the subquery. Try building a List from the join and then making a set of `programme_number` beans from said list.

Comment: It's an Oracle join not standard ANSI join.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested?